# webcam problem with skype on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, skype, webcam

I am runing ubuntu 9.10 and the latest version of skype but I have problem with webcam. When I trie the webcam with cheese it works fine but when I try to use the web on skype , skype crashes. can any body help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype cannot directly interact with video4linux. You need to load an extra library (v4l1compat.so) for the compatibility layer:

```
# LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

Maybe you need to adjust the library path for your setup.

To make this permanent just add this variable to /usr/bin/skype: add

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so; export LD_PRELOAD
```

e.g. on the 2nd line there.

Maybe you also want to report this in your distribution's bugtracker.

Comment: Thank you man, it works. but please tell me can make this permanent change.

Comment: Man, you are the best! Does this solution works for any video conferencing application?

Comment: Where do you add this line?  /usr/bin/skype is a binary file, no?

Comment: Where should i add this lines?

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but the problem still exists.
As honk says, setting LD_PRELOAD to the v4l1compat.so library works.

On my 64-bit ubuntu 12.04, this worked:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

I have a 32 bit skype, so the library should match that.

I want to launch skype with a panel icon. I put this in the command field:

```
bash -c "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype"
```

This avoids creating a separate script file. Without bash however, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add to the /usr/bin/skype file either (it is a binary file).    Anyhow here is my workaround:

1) in my home folder I made a file (using gedit) that contained -

```
#! /bin/bash

LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

2) then added an application link to my menus -

```
bash /home/yourusername/skype_with_video.sh
```

(the Skype icon should be in the /usr/share/icons/ folder for the link)

Not elegant, but it works.